# Can I use latest Capistrano which requires ruby >2, to deploy Rails application that requires ruby 1.9.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, ruby-1.9.3

I want to automate a legacy application deployment with Capistrano, but the application requires ruby 1.9.3, and Capistrano, as of this writing, requires at least ruby 2. Would it still be possible to use ruby 2+ with latest capistrano on my local dev machine to deploy to remote server that only has ruby 1.9.3 installed?

Comment: Ruby 1.9.3 has been EOL for a year and a half. I would make updating the ruby version your first priority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Capistrano to deploy any framework so the servers ruby version is irrelevant. Capistrano is just a rake DSL that does stuff remotely via FTP or SSH.

If you install it via gem install and not via bundler you can get around any problems with the Gemfile.

But switching back and forth between ruby versions in development or not using the same version as production seems like a disaster waiting to happen.

I would upgrade ruby first. The worry about setting up capistrano.

Comment: Thanks, plans are there to upgrade things as much as possible, including ruby, but there's no automated deployment and roll-back for the current application, and it's live in production, so I can't just take risks without first making sure I can get it deploying as is.